# Floating label on custom TextField moves when keyboard appears only on big device

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I've developed a custom textField in SwiftUI that features a floating label as a placeholder. The label moves up when the user starts tapping in the textField.

In my LoginView, I've centered my TextFields. The problem is, when the user touch inside the textField, the keyboard pops up and makes the placeholder of the current textField do weird moves, as well as the placeholders of all other textFields, then move back to their initial position.

[TextField-bug] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAM2y.gif)

Here is the code of my view:

```
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ZStack {
                    VStack {
                        if !isTextFieldEditing {
                            imageTE
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    VStack {
                        
                        TETextField("ei_apple_login_mail_address", text: $viewModel.email)
                            .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                            .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                            .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                            .padding(.top, .medium)
                            .disabled(!viewModel.isTextFieldActive)
                        
                        TESecureField("ei_apple_login_password", text: $viewModel.password)
                            .keyboardType(.default)
                            .textContentType(.password)
                            .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                            .padding(.top, .regular)
                            .disabled(!viewModel.isTextFieldActive)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationFlowLink(isActive: $viewModel.showPasswordRecovery) {
                                ResetPasswordNavigationFlow(context: .passwordRecovery)
                            } label: {
                                Text("ei_apple_login_forgot_password")
                            }
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.appleBlue)
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: login) {
                            Text("ei_apple_login_cta")
                                .loading(viewModel.isLoading)
                        }
                        .disabled(viewModel.isLoading)
                        .buttonStyle(.primary)
                        .padding([.top, .bottom], .large)
                        .disabled(!viewModel.formIsValid)
                        .customAlert(
                            "ei_common_alert_reactivate_account_title",
                            message: "ei_common_alert_reactivate_account_desc",
                            isPresented: $viewModel.showAccountDeactivatedAlert
                        ) {
                            CustomAlertButton(
                                "ei_common_alert_reactivate_account_cta",
                                role: .destructive,
                                action: reactivateAccount
                            )
                            CustomAlertButton("alert_title_cancel", role: .cancel) { }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(horizontal: .medium, vertical: .regular))
                }
                
            }
            .background(Color.background1.ignoresSafeArea())
            .foregroundColor(.body)
            .navigationBarBackButtonDisplayMode(.minimal)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .customNavigationTitle("ei_apple_login_title")
            .toast(viewModel.toastMessage, isPresented: $viewModel.showToast, kind: viewModel.toastKind)
            .onChange(of: viewModel.didFinishLogin, perform: onFinish)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            // Hide keyboard when user touch the view
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)) { _ in
            // Hide TE logo when keyboard apears
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                isTextFieldEditing = true
            }
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
            // show TE logo when keyboard disapears
            withAnimation {
                isTextFieldEditing = false
            }
        }
    }
```

This issue seems to occur only on the iPhone Pro and Pro Max in iOS 16.2, and not on smaller devices. I'm wondering if anyone has experienced a similar problem or has any suggestions for how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Without a [mre], no one can run your code and the chances of a solution here are dramatically decreased.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.